# Issue with loading images using Codeigniter and Nginx

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx

I just migrated a normal Apache server to a server with Nginx that has a website configured with Codeigniter. Within this site, there is a controller that handles the upload of images using the upload library of Codeigniter. The disadvantage is that when using only Apache the images loaded correctly. But now, with nginx, the same controller (without having changed anything) says that the image loads correctly but in the folder where it should be saved there is no image.

Any idea why this behavior happens?

This is the code of my controller:

```
            $data['username'] = $this->session->userdata['username'];
            $data['password'] = $this->session->userdata['password'];
            $email = $data['username'];

            $config['upload_path'] = './uploads_imgperfil/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
            $config['file_name'] = 'imagen';
            $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
            $config['max_size'] = 3000;
            $config['max_width'] = 2048;
            $config['max_height'] = 2048;

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if ($this->upload->do_upload("file")) {

                $fileName = $_POST['fileName'];

                //Obtengo la extensión del archivo
                $extension = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                //Obtengo el ID del candidato
                $name_candidato = $this->model_edicion_perfil->obtener_name($data['username']);
                $id_registro = $name_candidato->idcandidato;

                $thumb = '_'.$id_registro;

                $configx['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                $configx['source_image'] = './uploads_imgperfil/imagen.'.$extension;
                $configx['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
                $configx['thumb_marker'] = $thumb;
                $configx['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
                $configx['width'] = 310;
                $configx['height'] = 233;

                $this->load->library('image_lib', $configx);
                $this->image_lib->resize();

                //Por ultimo borro la imagen que el subio
                unlink('./uploads_imgperfil/imagen.'.$extension);

                $image_name = 'imagen_'.$id_registro.'.'.$extension;

                $data = array(
                    'image_perfil' => $image_name
                );

                $consulta = $this->model_edicion_perfil->update_imgperfil($email, $data);
                $this->ultima_actualizacion($email);

                $result = array(
                    'message' => 'Imagen cargada correctamente.',
                    'flag' => 1,
                    'image' => $image_name
                );

            }else{

                $result = array(
                    'message' => $this->upload->display_errors(),
                    'flag' => 0
                );

            }
```

And my nginx configuration file looks like this:

```
server {
    ## Escucha en el puerto 80 (HTTP)
    listen   80;

    ## Raíz donde se encuentra la página Web
    root /var/www/example.com/public_html/example;

    ## Orden de prioridad de los archivos index
     index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name example.com;

     location / {
      #  index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

      location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
         fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
     }

     location ~ /\.ht {
         deny all;
     }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Uploading in PHP has little to do with nginx or apache, however, it could be the difference with how php is set up on both.  Were you using the same php-fpm process?  Does it have the same owner/permissions?

Comment: That's a really good question.  I think the main difference that we have to mention is that I was using PHP5, now I'm using PHP7.  I know its a big difference but the main things (configuration) its the same.. Do I have to change anything related to permissions?